# Parse Android SDK nested saveInBackground not working

Tags: android, parsing, callback

I'm working on an existing Android App with parse back-end (localDatastore is enabled but not used in this context) which has the following object structure:

Object A has an array of objects B

Object B has an array of objects C

I save this object structure using saveInBackground in calling the next saveInBackground in the done SaveCallback in reverse Order(C,B,A). For the inner two that works fine, but the top level object isn't saved.
Here's the code (frame, newStep and order are objects of classes inheriting from the ParseObject class)

```
frame.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.i("Info", "frame.save callback OK");
                frames.add(frame);
                newStep.setTimeFrames(frames);
                newStep.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.i("Info", "newStep.save callback OK");
                            List<ProcessingStep> steps = order.getProcessingSteps();
                            steps.add(newStep);
                            order.setProcessingSteps(steps);
                            order.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null){
                                        Log.i("Info", "order.save callback OK");
                                    }else{
                                        Log.i("Info", "order.save callback FAIL");
                                    }
                                }});
                        } else {
                            Log.i("Info", "newStep.save callback FAIL");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.i("Info", "frame.save callback FAIL");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

In the console log I see only "frame.save callback OK", the "newStep.saveInBackground()" seems to be executed too (object appears in backend) however I never get the log message in the callback.

If I save all objects before synchronously without references to each other first and then call the code here, it seems to work (worked at least once) but took for ever (minutes). Queries from the back-end are super fast and the frame object is also saved almost instantly but the done-callbacks seem to bugging. When it fails I do not get any exception, log anything it just seems to fail silently.

I'm looking for any insight why Parse behaves like that as well as how to fix it.

**edit:** The problem seems to be with the double relation (A to B and B to C). If I try with only A to B or B to C it works just fine. What remains mysterious to me, however, is why splitting the operation up with callbacks doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It seems there is an issue storing the newStep object, since you don't see the "newStep.save callback OK" log. Can you post your NewStep class code ? Can you check your Parse server logs ?

Comment: The parse server logs are clean. The newStep object's class just extends ParseObject implements Parcelable (with just a bunch of getters and setters)

Comment: What are its attributes ? Any peculiarity ?

Comment: the most noteable is an array of pointer to the lowest object (frames in the code snippet above).

Comment: Are you sure all the frames in the timeFrames array are stored in Parse before storing the newStep ?

Comment: pretty much, for the testcase I used there was only one. I now set the one relation before and it even works if I don't save them before and parse takes care of saving the children. However that only works if I clean the app cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the enabled localdatastore. Without localdatastore enabled everything works as it should.